# R Markdown: Create PDF in a folder A and save PDF in another folder B

Tags: r, pdf, directory, markdown, r-markdown

I have a problem with R Markdown:

I've created an PDF-File (out of the file: "example.Rmd") in a folder called A.

In the folder A there is another folder called B.

So my example.Rmd is in folder A, but now I want to have the created PDF-File in folder B, so when I hit the knit-Button, the PDF-File will go to the folder B.

How can I do this? Is there any code for that?

Thank you already for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of specifying .pdf output folder. However, you can change the working directory of the document. Hit down arrow beside Knit button and check knit directory.

Some more discussion can be found [on this link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007318867-A-directory-to-save-knitted-document-report-in-R-Markdown-Notebook)